# Swing paint method

Tags: java, swing, paint, repaint

I have problem in paint method in a `JPanel`.
At first I create a class that extends `JFrame`.
Then I create a class that extends panel and create a object from this class and add to frame.

I want by pressing the right button on keyboard (`VK_RIGHT`) the little rectangles be drawn on panel Within 2 seconds. (That means rectangle clear and be drawn in a new location. My problem  is: I can not do timing paint method and repaint method. I wish every two seconds rectangle go ahead for 5 times (step by step) but rectangle go ahead just one.

my codes are:

### `Panel`

```
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel{

    private int x;
    private int y;
    public Panel()
    {
        x=100;
        y=100;
        this.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    //--------------------------------

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    }

    //--------------------------------

    @Override
    public void repaint()
    {
        super.repaint();

        x+=20;
    }

    //--------------------------------
}
```

### `Frame`

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private Panel p;

    public Frame()
    {
        super("Test");
        this.setBounds(1200, 300, 400, 400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p=new Panel();
        this.add(p);


        this.addKeyListener(new KeyLis());
    }

    //----------------------------------

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame a=new Frame();

        a.setVisible(true);
    }

    //-----------------------------------

    private class KeyLis implements KeyListener
    {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    p.repaint();
                }
            }
        }
        //---------------
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        //---------------
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        //---------------
    }
    //-----------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: You could get familiar with the ExecutorService of JAVA. Take a SingleThreadExecutor and execute() 5 Threads. They will get processed serially.

Comment: Your problem, primarily, is the for-loop in the KeyListener, which is blocking the Event dispatching thread, preventing updates from been painted. Simple solution is to use a Swing Timer, it waits in the background, triggers ticks on the EDT, making safe it update the ui from and schedules updates a regular intervals

Comment: Recommendations: override paintComponent instead of paint as a general rule. Don't use repaint to update your state, you may not be the only one calling it, instead, create a model which can be shared between the view and you key controller. I'd also discourage the use of KeyListener and make use of the key bindings API instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are set on using a Thread:

Changed your KeyPressed event to:

```
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

            if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                PaintThread th = new PaintThread(p);
                th.start();
            }
        }
```

Created a Thread:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PaintThread extends Thread{

    Panel panel;

    PaintThread(Panel panel){
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
            try {
                this.sleep(1000);
                panel.repaint();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PaintThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just beware that Swing is not thread safe - `repaint` is among the few methods that is, but as a general rule, one should avoid using `Thread` when other (safer) means are generally available ... just saying that this could take OP down a nasty path

Answer (score 2):

Your problem, primarily, is the `for-loop` in the `KeyListener`, which is blocking the Event dispatching thread, preventing updates from been painted.

Simple solution is to use a Swing `Timer`, it waits in the background, triggers ticks on the EDT, making safe it update the ui from and schedules updates at regular intervals.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

If, for some reason, you find Swing `Timer` to difficult to comprehend, you could also try using a `SwingWorker`, which will allow you to use a background thread to loop in, but which provides methods to update states within the context of the EDT.

See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

## Recommendations

Override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` as a general rule. See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Don't use `repaint` to update your state, you may not be the only one calling it, instead, create a model which can be shared between the view and you key controller.

See [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) for some ideas

I'd also discourage the use of `KeyListener` and make use of the key bindings API instead

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: tanks my friend